# undefined reference to `demo::app::ApplicationDemo::entry()'

Tags: c++, cmake

I am trying to nest code under specific `namespace` for organizational purposes. Below is an MVP, I cannot spot the issue in my code. Not sure how you define this nesting or export it to `CMakeLists.txt` and Linking. It happens only if a wrap the class inside `namespaces`.

**demo.h:**

```
#pragma once
#include "../../third-party/fmt/include/fmt/core.h"
#include "../../third-party/fmt/include/fmt/color.h"

namespace demo {
    namespace app {
        class ApplicationDemo{
        public:
            void entry();
        };
    }
}
```

**demo.cpp:**

```
#include "demo.h"

namespace demo
{
    namespace app {
        void ApplicationDemo::entry(){
             std::string m_ascii = R"(
    ____                   
    |    \  ___  _____  ___ 
    |  |  || -_||     || . |
    |____/ |___||_|_|_||___|                    
)";
            fmt::print(fmt::emphasis::bold | fg(fmt::color::orange_red), m_ascii);
        }
    }
}
```

**main.cpp:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "demoapp/demo.h"

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    demo::app::ApplicationDemo m_demo;

    m_demo.entry();
    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

**CMakeLists.txt:**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
project(demo)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS
        "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} \
        -Wall \
        -fdiagnostics-color=always \
        -mavx")

set(CMAKE_WINDOWS_EXPORT_ALL_SYMBOLS ON)
set(CMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/lib)
set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/lib)
set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin)

include_directories(./)

add_subdirectory(third-party/fmt EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL)
target_compile_options(fmt PRIVATE -w)

add_subdirectory(src/demoapp)

set(third_parties fmt)

set(SOURCES src/main.cpp)
add_executable(demo src/main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(demo ${third_parties})
```

**Build output:**

```
[main] Building folder: experiment 
[build] Starting build
[proc] Executing command: chcp
[proc] Executing command: "C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.EXE" --build c:/GitHub/experiment/build --config Debug --target all -j 10 --
[build] [ 20%] Building CXX object third-party/fmt/CMakeFiles/fmt.dir/src/format.cc.obj
[build] [ 40%] Building CXX object third-party/fmt/CMakeFiles/fmt.dir/src/os.cc.obj
[build] [ 60%] Linking CXX static library ..\..\lib\libfmtd.a
[build] [ 60%] Built target fmt
[build] [ 80%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/demo.dir/src/main.cpp.obj
[build] [100%] Linking CXX executable bin\demo.exe
[build] C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: CMakeFiles\demo.dir/objects.a(main.cpp.obj): in function `main':
[build] C:/GitHub/experiment/src/main.cpp:8:(.text+0x1c): undefined reference to `demo::app::ApplicationDemo::entry()'
[build] collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
[build] mingw32-make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles\demo.dir\build.make:100: bin/demo.exe] Error 1
[build] mingw32-make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles\Makefile2:98: CMakeFiles/demo.dir/all] Error 2
[build] mingw32-make: *** [Makefile:135: all] Error 2
[proc] The command: "C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.EXE" --build c:/GitHub/experiment/build --config Debug --target all -j 10 -- exited with code: 2
[driver] Build completed: 00:00:04.365
[build] Build finished with exit code 2
```

---

**EDIT: I put things like this,**

```
/src/demoapp/
CMakeLists.txt,
demo.cpp
demo.h

/src/main.cpp
```

**The CMakeLists.txt of demoapp:**

```
add_library(demoapp
demo.cpp)

target_link_libraries(demoapp fmt)

if(WIN32)
    target_link_libraries(demoapp)
else()
    target_link_libraries(demoapp stdc++fs)
endif()
```

Then, I added this line `add_subdirectory(src/demoapp)` to the parent root CMakeLists.txt. But, when I do this, which is my desired goal. Sorry I didn't specify this earlier, when I receive the same error as above. Whereas, if I do the way you showed me, then it works brilliantly.

I appreciate any valuable information on this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to add `demo.cpp` to your executable. It is not being compiled and linked as part of the project.

```
add_executable(demo
    src/main.cpp
    src/demo.cpp
    src/demo.h)
```

*Note: adding `demo.h` to the executable isn't strictly necessary, but useful for IDEs because it makes the header part of the project. For example, QtCreator relies on this.*

`void ApplicationDemo::entry()` is located in `demo.cpp`, and if if you don't add `demo.cpp` to the executable, the definitions inside won't be available to the rest of the program, and you get linker errors.

Furthermore, if you want link to a library, it is necessary to write:

```
target_link_libraries(demo demoapp)
```

Merely adding a subdirectory where `demoapp` is located isn't enough; it doesn't yet tell CMake that the library is linked with the `demo` executable.

*See also [CMake link library from subdirectory](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30030885/5740428)*

Comment: Why can't it be done the way, I have done it there? With: `add_library()` in a CMakeLists.txt under the src/demoapp ?

Comment: @AlixBlaine did you link the `demo` executable with the `demoapp` library using `target_link_libraries` ? I don't see that in your code

Comment: What do you mean Jan?

Comment: @AlixBlaine I see you have linked `target_link_libraries(demo ${third_parties})`, but shouldn't you also have linked `target_link_libraries(demo demoapp)` ?

Comment: Demo app is my own code not third-party, shouldn't it be enough to `add_subdirectory(src/demoapp)` ?

Comment: @AlixBlaine `add_subdirectory` just adds a directory to the build. It doesn't mean that all executables will be linked to all libraries that you have created in the directory. It just lets CMake know that a subdirectory is somehow involved in the build process.

Comment: Yes, but, it produces a *.dll for my own code the demoapp, can I tell it to statically link and embed that one?

Comment: @AlixBlaine see [CMake: include library dependencies in a static library](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14199708/5740428)